# MVC - HTML.ActionLink to download file - How to handle and report failures

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a button on an MVC webpage that downloads a file:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Connect", "DownloadFile", "Results", new { ResultID = Model.Result.ResultID }, new { @id = "connect-btn", @style = "display:none"})
```

The controller returns a file:

```
return File(stream, "text/plain", fullName + ".txt");
```

This works fine except there is a potential problem in the DownloadFile method in the controller where the file returned is incorrect i.e empty. The controller has been changed so that in this event it returns NULL or it could return new EmptyResult(?)

When this happens, in the View i want it to stop/ignore downloading the empty file and display a page message "download failed".

I've tried writing a javascript function (instead of using an ActionLink) on button click but:

$.post call - would work but i need to add [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken] to the header which I understand cannot be done with jquery posts (I have tried)

$.ajax call - does not work by design with downloaded files.

Any advice on how to solve this? I just need it so that when the assembled file is identified as incorrect, the View displays a message rather than giving the user an incorrect file?

Comment: Change your link to open in `target="_new"` then throw an exception from the Action - the exception will be displayed in the new tab - added bonus, the new tab will have a "progress" indicator while the document is generated/downloaded.

Comment: Add a pre-validation step (eg with an ajax call) to check/validate the document, then auto-click the download button when it passes (improved UX)

Comment: *but i[sic] need to add [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken] to the header* - how are you doing this with the current `@Html.ActionLink` which just creates `<a href='your_action'>Connect</a>`

Comment: The issue is that `<a href=` navigates to a new page (your document) - so your page immediately loses control.   You can't navigate away from a page and then catch if it fails.

Comment: The controller method was [HttpGet] and did not have [ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]. Changing it it [HttpPost] as part of this fix flagged the vulnerability and that it was now required.

There is no <a href= in the View button at the moment? Clicking the button just downloads  the file to the Downloads folder, it doesnt navigate away to a new page.

Comment: Open page, view source.  The code that you've provided: `@Html.ActionLink(` generates `<a href=` HTML.   It doesn't pass the token and makes a `GET` request.  If you've changed the action to `[HttpPost]` then your @Html.ActionLink won't work.   Any click on a `<a>` will navigate away from the current page - if the page navigated to is a download, then the browser will cancel the navigation,  download the file and leave you on your current page.   Once you click a `<a href>` you have no further control on what happens to/on the page/link that the href refers to.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m - learned a lot about jquery. Managed to resolve it from your suggestions, i now have a <code> .click(function </code> on the button which then does a $.get to the controller and reports an error if the file data is empty.

The actionlink ended up like:
<code>Html.ActionLink("Connect", "", "", null, new { id = "connect-btn", style = "display:none", disabled = "disabled", href = "#" }) </code>

Comment: I did try adding an onclick call to a return js function and then return false on failureto the ActionLink but no matter what I tried it still done a second call to the controller from the actionlink, like it wasnt even waiting for the js to return - I had to null out the method/controller and model data to stop this and just build the download file in the onclick function.